# Hash equals does not behave as should

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I am trying to follow the password tutorial as provided [here](https://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/). I got adding users to work (my salt is hard coded for now - `mcrypt_create_iv` is missing) . Anyhow, when I follow up on checking the password, I get false and the hashes differ.

```
hash_equals($user->hash, crypt($password, $user->hash))
```

I am getting `*0` for `$user->hash` and `*1` for `crypt($password, $user->hash)` ? They should be equal per tutorial.

What do the values mean by the way? `*0` to me seems that my password encrypting function does not work?

Here's my code for encrypting the password:

```
$cost = 10;

    // Create a random salt
    #$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
    $salt = 'Banana';
    $salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
    $hash = crypt($password, $salt);
```

And by changing the salt and password combination I keep getting `*0`, so something must be wrong. Do I have to load some library? Seems something is missing, and I do not know what.

Comment: Please use the official password hash lib http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is that a standard approach to use the library?

Answer (score 2):

You should really just use the official password hash lib

```
$hash = password_hash('Banana', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 10]);

if (password_verify('Banana', $hash)) {
  echo 'Password is valid!';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: Hm, I got it running, thanks. But they write that with PHP updates, PASSWORD_DEFAULT could change. When that happens, all hashes in my password DB would change too, no?

Comment: @ElDude *It is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)* - old passwords will stay presented as valid and actual 60 symbols hashes; the new ones, however, may be longer (up to 255). `password_verify` for sure will be smart enough to work with both versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash_equals($user->hash, crypt($password, $user->hash))
```

here you are checking if user->hash is equals to $password crypted with, as salt, the user->hash instead of comparating it with password crypted with the salt as below:

```
hash_equals($user->hash, crypt($password, $salt))
```

Also i'll suggest using password_hash() and password_verify() functions to do it.